# Confusion regarding mx, my variables in costmap_2d::worldToMap method

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, costmap-2d, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The  `worldToMap` function is defined as follows in the official [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/electric/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html) - `worldToMap (double wx, double wy, unsigned int &mx, unsigned int &my) const`.

What are the variables `mx` and `my`? I am not sure but `wx` and `wy` represent the points that we want to transform to the map frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369271/confusion-regarding-mx,-my-variables-in-costmap_2d::worldtomap-method/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation:

> Parameters:
> wx - The x world coordinate
> wy - The y world coordinate
> mx - Will be set to the associated map x coordinate
> my - Will be set to the associated map y coordinate

Essentially, the world coordinates are in meters and the map coordinates are in pixels.  This function doesn't transform between frames in the tf tree; it converts physical coordinates (e.g., [meters] in the `map` frame) into image coordinates in the current `costmap` image, using an origin shift and scaling by the `costmap` resolution.  Here's the function implementation for clarity:

```
00548   bool Costmap2D::worldToMap(double wx, double wy, unsigned int& mx, unsigned int& my) const {
00549     if(wx < origin_x_ || wy < origin_y_)
00550       return false;
00551 
00552     mx = (int) ((wx - origin_x_) / resolution_);
00553     my = (int) ((wy - origin_y_) / resolution_);
00554 
00555     if(mx < size_x_ && my < size_y_)
00556       return true;
00557 
00558     return false;
00559   }
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-11**:
Thank you.